# To update a table using update statement using join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which is of the format

Table 1

```
COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4   COL5  COL6
aaaa  92809 ndjhd  3948309 NULL  90340
aaaa  90343 nadfj  1212121 NULL  21000
bbbb  20392 ndaop  2389299 NULL  23874
```

Table 1 should be updated by taking values from other table which is of format

Table 2

```
COL1 COL2  COL5
aaaa 92809 345
bbbb 20392 293
```

I use the following update statemnt to update col5 in table1 with values from col5 in table2

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.col5=B.col5
    FROM table1 A
    INNER JOIN (select distinct col1,col2,col5 from table2) B
    ON A.col1=B.Col1
```

The problem i am facing is that this update statement is only updating the first row.How do i update COL 5 of table1 where ever the COL1 matches between both the tables.

Comment: It seems OK to me like this, surely only the first row gets updated?

Comment: when col1 is aaaa then first two rows should be updated in the table1 but for me only the first row is updated and then for col1 bbbb row 3 is updated. Row 2 is left with 'NULL' value in col 5.Please help

Comment: You can also try to replace `UPDATE A  SET A.col5=B.col5` with `SELECT *` and see what you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems correct. Test that 'aaaa' contains no space. Here is a simple query to test.

```
select a.*, case when exists(select 1 from table2 b where b.col1=a.col1) then 'columns equal' else 'columns different' end col5_compare
from table1 a
```

Comment: thanks! i used LTRIM AND RTRIM to eliminate the space and it worked perfect!!